# Sapper.js - Preload with cookies/headers?

Tags: javascript, authentication, aws-lambda, svelte, sapper

I'm using Sapper.js to power my application but only using the static content created by running `sapper export`. So there is no server rendering the pages.

I'm using AWS CloudFront with Lambda@Edge to perform authentication on the user's `HttpOnly` cookies whenever they request a page. If the user is authenticated, Lambda will then fetch user data such as the user's profile picture, username, etc and set these values in custom headers/cookies (non HttpOnly) on the pages returned by CloudFront.

These values can be set in either headers or cookies, there are no requirements for either.

But I need to have this dynamic content available to the client before the page is rendered in order to avoid an ugly flash of empty content. So it should be retrieved inside of sapper's `preload` function instead of `onMount` in order to stall any other html from being rendered until the data is returned.

I know how to fetch inside of the `preload` function like so:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload(page, session) {
        const res = await this.fetch("SOME_ENDPOINT");
        const data = await res.json();

        return {data};
    }
</script>
```

but I'm not sure on how to get access to headers or cookies from within this function.

**EDIT: NEW APPROACH?**

So I've been thinking and it seems like the best way to go at this point is to try and transform Sapper's `sapper.middleware` function so that it accepts a custom `req` object and returns the `res` object instead of trying to serve it to the client.

Then we can run `npm run build` and use the entire `build` directory inside of Lambda. We're free to pass any user data into the middleware `session` obbject afterwards as it explains in the docs:

```
sapper.middleware({session: (CUSTOM_REQ, CUSTOM_RES) => ({user: CUSTOME_REQ.user})})
```

No need to fetch any data as it should now be available in the `store`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm suffering the same issue

Comment: I feel you. Read my edit and let me know if you have any ideas on my new approach

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `{ credentials: true }` as the second option to `this.fetch` (same as regular `fetch`):

```js
export async function preload(page, session) {
    const res = await this.fetch("SOME_ENDPOINT", {
        credentials: true
    });
    const data = await res.json();

    return {data};
}
```

This will cause cookies to be sent with the request. By definition though, this won't work with exported apps — the response must be constructed per-user.

Comment: This doesn't work for my case because the cookies are not being sent by the client but are being set by Lambda@Edge and received by the client. Flow is like this: User -> GET CloudFront Endpoint (with any cookies saved by browser) -> CloudFront returns html page where app lives -> Lambda@Edge injects headers/cookies depending on auth -> html page and headers returned to user. So these values are returned before the page even loads. I could skip the Lambda function and call an auth API with the method above but that would incur latency and provide an extra HTTP request

Comment: `{ credentials: 'same-origin' }` or `{ credentials: 'include' }` works in my case, I guess `{ credentials: true }` is for `require('cors')` or something